# Open modal before showing main content on app resume

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

In my ionic app, I'm showing lockscreen modal when app resumes. I wanna show the app content only when user has successfully entered the correct pin else the app is minimizing. My problem is the delay of viewing modal. Modal is being shown after some time and in that time the app is already loaded and all the content of app is visible for some time which I don't want. In case of starting the app I successfully solved this issue by implementing `APP_INITIALIZE` functionality in which modal is viewed first and after that the main content of app is loaded. But I can't achieve the same functionality in pause/resume methods. Here's my code:

**app.component.ts**

```
initializeApp() {
    this.platform.pause.subscribe(async () => {
      const time = (await Storage.get({key: 'pauseTimeout'})).value;
      this.pauseTimeout = Number(time + '000');
      this.timeout = false;
      this.timeoutObj = setTimeout(() => {
        this.timeout = true;
      }, this.pauseTimeout);
    });
    this.platform.resume.subscribe(() => {
      clearTimeout(this.timeoutObj);
      if (this.timeout) {
        this.userService.loggedIn_()
          .then(async loggedIn => {
            if (loggedIn) {
              const cred = await this.userService.getCredentials_();
              if (cred && cred.passcode) {
                const passModal = await this.modalController.create({
                  component: PasscodePage,
                  componentProps: { passMethod: 'accessApp' }
                });
                await passModal.present();
              }
            }
          });
      }
    });
```

Basically, I'm showing a modal if `pauseTimeout` is reached. But as some time is already spent in `loggedIn` verification, the main content of app already loads in that time. Is there any way to load that content after modal dismissal?

Comment: Could you use a route guard that redirects to a lockscreen page instead of a lockscreen modal? The route guard would test if the user is logged in & pin exists. If yes, the guard is bypassed. If no, navigate to lockscreen for pin submission.

Comment: @RichTillis Thanks for suggestion. I'll try it and let you know.